# When I click a link in the react webpage, all components are reloading. Why is that?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am creating a simple react project. I created an addStudent page. When I go through the link (../add), All components reload including Navbar. I want to reload only addStudent page without reloading Navbar. Can anyone help me?.

App.js

```js
import React from "react";
import Header from "./components/header";
import AddStudent from "./components/addStudent";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Header />

        <Route path="/add" component={AddStudent} />

      </div>
    </Router>

  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Add another "container" component and do Route there. and then use "container" in App

Comment: you forget to use <Switch></Switch>

Comment: @Haikel I tried but same problem

Comment: @NikitaChayka Can you explain in more detail?